# How to rotate a whole HTML5 document?

Tags: html, safari, rotation, markup

I have an HTML5 game in a iBooks Widget. 
It turns out the "close widget" button doesn't obey the information in Info.plist, which means it ends up right on top of the play zone.

I can either recode the whole logic, and flip every single image (not that much work, but not a great solution,indeed), or if possible rotate the whole document by 180deg.

I've tried applying

```
-webkit-transform: rotate(180deg); 
-webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
```

to the body element, but this doesn't rotate the background image on Safari, among other issues.

Hence the question,is there something I can add to the document header to ask it to render itself rotated by a halfturn?

Answer (score 0):

No Safari for testing here, however, applying your CSS properties to html instead of body works as expected in Chrome.

Comment: Actually, it's a purely iBooks question. Thx anyway!

Comment: Sorry, don't know what an I-Book is. Thought it has something like a html-element, too.